# It is possible to obtain a CreationalContext from producer in CDI?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

Let's say I have some a producer:

```
  @Produces
  public A producesA() {
     // ...
  }
```

Is any way to obtain a `CreationalContext` object inside producer? I've walked through the invocation stack and it seems to me that CreationalContext becomes lost. But it might be there is a way how to retrieve it?

Comment: There is no way to do that (neither in CDI nor in Weld). Can you expand on why you need that? And maybe we can figure out a different approach?

Comment: @Siliarus A CreationalContext provides a convenient tree of dependencies inclusion, what covers all managed beans and so on. The usage of this stuff are details. Just believe me: I need access to this tree for retrieving some missed data about top-level injection

Comment: It's not like I don't believe you, I am just asking because there is truly no built-in way to obtain it. Feel free to create a [JIRA ticket for Weld](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) and describe the use-case there and you might just see it in future versions.

Comment: You can always inject beans or `Instance<X>`s as arguments to the producer method, if need be. Or your problem (if complex enough) could be solved by an extension. I am curious too as for why would you be needing the `CreationalContext`, but I believe you :) so good luck with it!

Comment: The only and the best way to use `CreationalContext` is when you implement an extension. This is where it is meant to be used, and offers you the best scenario to manipulate anyt creational contextual logic. Change the produce to use an Extension, and you can grab the CreationalContext when registering the bean